# scroll zoom on two images

Tags: javascript, event-handling, zooming

I have two images with same dimensions and same positions, but placed in divs with dynamic width depending on user interaction using the [jquery beforeAfter plugin](http://www.catchmyfame.com/2009/06/25/jquery-beforeafter-plugin/).

I would like to enable scroll zooming on these images using [wheelzoom](http://www.jacklmoore.com/wheelzoom/), such that zooming on one of these images will zoom the same amount in the same position as the other.

What I am unable to do is this linking of (I suppose) the event handlers along the lines of this:

```
function onwheel(e){
    //adjust image to fit zoom level ...

    other_img.onwheel(e);
}
```

If this is not possible, is it possible to copy the event and change the target image?

I am looking for a solution using either jquery or native Javascript.

[Code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RjHhw65opIU2f2k8aiNa?p=preview) (ignore the handle).

EDIT: Any top-level pointers to what should work would also be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a worked example: http://plnkr.co/edit/kH0ec8TVMXUIYlMoBaMq?p=preview

here is the core code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("before")[0].addEventListener("wheel", function(event){
  if(flag){
    flag= false;
    return;
  };
  flag=true;
  var newEvent = new WheelEvent("wheel",event);
  var elementToTrigger = document.getElementsByClassName("after")[0]; 
  elementToTrigger.dispatchEvent(newEvent);
});
```

I do something simple, when an event happening("wheel") a trigger the same event to another element and pass as argument the data from the first event to the new event. I use flag variable to deter the custom event trigger again the other event and start an eternal loop.

This is a solution without to edit the source code of plugin. You can do more good solutions if you change the code of wheelzoom.js.

Comment: How would you recommend doing it, assuming I edit wheelzoom.js (without going into too many details)?

Comment: You can do the library to take two or more elements, like this: wheelzoom($('.before'),$('.after')); and make it act like one. The library will be found when an event happened and will zoom in an array of elements and not just in one, so no need to trigger a new event. Note: Will be more easier if you refactor the library to use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Make the zooming a function that takes enough parameters to handle zooming, and get the values you need from the event handler.

```
function handleZoom(domNode, zoomDirection, zoomAmount) {
    // Do stuff to change the size of `domNode`
}

var img1, img2;

img1 = /* select image node */;
img2 = /* select image node */;

function handleScroll(scrollEvent) {
    var direction, amount;

    // Use `scrollEvent` to figure out which direction and how far to zoom

    handleZoom(img1, direction, amount);
    handleZoom(img2, direction, amount);
}

img1.onscroll = handleScroll;
img2.onscroll = handleScroll;
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need information from the event to determine `zoomDirection` and `zoomAmount` so you can pass it to `handleZoom`? Could you make that part more explicit?

Comment: Changed `e` to `scrollEvent` in that handler and made the comment more explicit. Getting information from the event is 100% the point of that function.

Comment: @M.T does that help?

Comment: I still don't see how you pass information from `scrollEvent` to `direction` or `amount` in your function